# code: 'ERR_DLOPEN_FAILED' issue or \node_modules\rollup\dist\native.js:60:48) issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vite

When I want to create a project with vite. After typing npm run dev, I get the following error. Can anyone help? I can't run the project.

```
Error: The specified module was not found
\\?\C:\Users\penso\OneDrive\MasaÃ¼stÃ¼\uyt\node_modules\@rollup\rollup-win32-x64-msvc\rollup.win32-x64-msvc.node
    at Module._extensions..node (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1327:18)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1091:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:938:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1115:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:130:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\penso\OneDrive\Masaüstü\uyt\node_modules\rollup\dist\native.js:60:48) //makes this place obvious
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1241:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1295:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1091:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:938:12) {
  code: 'ERR_DLOPEN_FAILED'
}
```

I tried to run the project with vite but it didn't work

Comment: Can you try to remove ```node_modules``` and ```package-lock.json```, and try again by ```npm install```, then  ```npm run dev```

Comment: `C:\Users\penso\OneDrive\ `    Not used Windows for a while, but I do know that DLL's have security considerations, and running from `OneDrive` might be one of those,   If you say tried doing `npm install` into say `C:\node` or some other none shared folder does it work OK.?

Comment: I tried both solutions you mentioned but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

As a solution, I deleted vs studio code and node.js and reinstalled them and the problem was solved.